# Particular value is not showing selected when data is coming from server

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown list:-

```
<label>User Names:</label>
<select ng-options="c as c.User for c in userList"
    ng-model="selectedUser" id="search3">
</select>
```

The data in this dropdown is coming from an API. My directive code:-

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.components')
        .directive('info', info);

    info.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout','ApiServices'];

    function info($http, $timeout, ApiServices) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {

            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                scope.newinfo = {};

                $('#info').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
                    scope.newinfo = {};
                });

                $('#info').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {  
                    scope.selectedUser = "EVAN";

    scope.getAllUsersName = function(){
        scope.userList = [];
        ApiServices.getAllUsersName().then(function (response) {
            scope.userList = response.data;//the data is an array of objects
        });
    }

    scope.getAllUsersName();


            //Link function ends below
            },
            templateUrl: 'js/folder/info.html'
        };
    }

})();
```

There is an User Name:- `EVAN`. I want this user to be selected whenever the page loads and shown on the select dropdown. I have tried multiple things like:-

```
ng-init="selectedUser = 'EVAN'"
ng-value="selectedUser = 'EVAN'"
scope.selectedUser = scope.userList[23].User
scope.selectedUser = "EVAN";Placed it inside the `scope.getAllUsersName` function and outside it too.
```

The value is assigning to the ng-model="selectedUser".But not showing in the dropdown. Can anyone tell me why it is not showing as the selected when when the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular `directives` has scope associated with them. By default, unless explicitly set, directives don’t create their own scope. They use their parent scope. Most of the time its a `controller's scope`.
You can change this default scope by using `scope:true` as below :

```
return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope:true,
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
          //your processing logic
        }
      }
```

You can also use an `isolated scope` if your directive wants to communicate with controller.

In your case, You should assign a selected user as :

```
scope.selectedUser = scope.userList[0]; //say "EVAN" at first position
```

Also, You should add your directive in a view like :

```
<select info="" ng-options="c as c.User for c in userList"
ng-model="selectedUser" id="search3">
```

I hope this would help you!!